# Removing direct left recursion in JavaCC

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, javacc, left-recursion

I have the following in a JavaCC file:

```
void condition() : {}
{
    expression() comp_op() expression()
    | condition() (<AND> | <OR>) condition()
}
```

where `<AND>` is "&&" and `<OR>` is "||". This is causing problems due to the fact that it is direct left-recursion. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A condition is essentially 1 or more of `expression comp_op expression` separated by an `AND` or an `OR`.  You could do the following

```
condition --> simpleCondition ( (<AND> | <OR>) simpleCondition )*
simpleCondition --> expression comp_op expression
```